# Compiler crash with a default inout value

Tags: xcode, swift

Warning: ** **Your computer may crash** **

With the following code in a command line project:

```
var err: NSError?

func foobar(inout error: NSError? = &err) {
}
```

I am getting the following crash at compile time :

> Assertion failed: (E->getType()->isMaterializable() && "l-values must
>   be emitted with emitLValue"), function emitRValue, file
>   /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/swiftlang/swiftlang-700.0.38.1/src/swift/lib/SILGen/SILGenExpr.cpp,
>   line 3695. 0  swift                    0x0000000111a84e0b
>   llvm::sys::PrintStackTrace(__sFILE*) + 43 1  swift
>   0x0000000111a8554b SignalHandler(int) + 379 2 
>   libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007fff8bf3cf1a _sigtramp + 26 3 
>   libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007fc80a90ca80 _sigtramp + 2124217216 4 
>   libsystem_c.dylib        0x00007fff9747eb53 abort + 129 5 
>   libsystem_c.dylib        0x00007fff97446c39 basename + 0 6  swift
>   0x000000010fcd361c
>   swift::Lowering::SILGenFunction::emitRValue(swift::Expr*,
>   swift::Lowering::SGFContext) + 76 7  swift
>   0x000000010fd2910a
>   swift::Lowering::SILGenFunction::emitReturnExpr(swift::SILLocation,
>   swift::Expr*) + 362 8  swift                    0x000000010fcf0b7c
>   swift::Lowering::SILGenFunction::emitGeneratorFunction(swift::SILDeclRef,
>   swift::Expr*) + 316 9  swift                    0x000000010fc92eb6
>   swift::Lowering::SILGenModule::emitDefaultArgGenerator(swift::SILDeclRef,
>   swift::Expr*) + 198 10 swift                    0x000000010fc919c7
>   swift::Lowering::SILGenModule::emitDefaultArgGenerators(llvm::PointerUnion, llvm::ArrayRef) + 295
>   11 swift                    0x000000010fc915d3
>   swift::Lowering::SILGenModule::emitAbstractFuncDecl(swift::AbstractFunctionDecl*)
>   + 163 12 swift                    0x000000010fc9131c swift::Lowering::SILGenModule::emitFunction(swift::FuncDecl*) + 44 13
>   swift                    0x000000010fc974bf
>   swift::ASTVisitor::visit(swift::Decl*) + 255 14 swift
>   0x000000010fc9428b
>   swift::Lowering::SILGenModule::emitSourceFile(swift::SourceFile*,
>   unsigned int) + 571 15 swift                    0x000000010fc9506f
>   swift::SILModule::constructSIL(swift::ModuleDecl*, swift::SILOptions&,
>   swift::FileUnit*, llvm::Optional, bool, bool) + 703 16
>   swift                    0x000000010fc9528b
>   swift::performSILGeneration(swift::FileUnit&, swift::SILOptions&,
>   llvm::Optional, bool) + 123 17 swift
>   0x000000010fa9e691 performCompile(swift::CompilerInstance&,
>   swift::CompilerInvocation&, llvm::ArrayRef, int&) + 9153
>   18 swift                    0x000000010fa9c0b3
>   frontend_main(llvm::ArrayRef, char const*, void*) + 2515
>   19 swift                    0x000000010fa9828f main + 1983 20
>   libdyld.dylib            0x00007fff91e025c9 start + 1

Is there a way around it?

Comment: What is your code supposed to do? Is that a default value for an inout parameter? How is it supposed to work?

Comment: Yes, It is a default value on an inout, In ObjC, I can test if the parameter passed in nil, not so in Swift so I made this construct and boom!

Comment: As for workarounds, use Swift 2.0 `throws` construct now. That is replacing `NSError` anyway.

Comment: I just realized that and went thru the refactoring. I <3 Swift 2.0. Thanks.